# Jar file execution errors Java / Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, jar, resources

I am having trouble with an exported jar for a game I made in Java. The game is due to be presented tomorrow and the jar will not execute.

I am running command java -jar filename.jar

Here is a part of the stack trace in the cmd prompt:

```
Image load failed: Resources/Images/shop/jet.png
javax.imageio.IIOException: Can't read input file!
        at javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(Unknown Source)
        at ImageLoader.loadImage(ImageLoader.java:21)
        at ImageLoader.loadScaledImage(ImageLoader.java:34)
        at ImgButton.<init>(ImgButton.java:18)
        at Carnies.createButtons(Carnies.java:343)
        at Carnies.simpleInitialize(Carnies.java:82)
        at Frame.<init>(Frame.java:90)
        at Carnies.<init>(Carnies.java:64)
        at CarnieRunner.makeGUI(CarnieRunner.java:62)
        at CarnieRunner.<init>(CarnieRunner.java:27)
        at CarnieRunner.main(CarnieRunner.java:131)
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
        at Carnies.createButtons(Carnies.java:361)
        at Carnies.simpleInitialize(Carnies.java:82)
        at Frame.<init>(Frame.java:90)
        at Carnies.<init>(Carnies.java:64)
        at CarnieRunner.makeGUI(CarnieRunner.java:62)
        at CarnieRunner.<init>(CarnieRunner.java:27)
        at CarnieRunner.main(CarnieRunner.java:131)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at GifHandler.<init>(GifHandler.java:15)
        at GifHandler.<clinit>(GifHandler.java:7)
        ... 7 more
```

It appears the problem is that my images aren't loading. Here is the line in the program that handles the image loading:

```
public static BufferedImage loadImage(String fileName) {
        try { 
            File file;
            file = new File(fileName);           
            BufferedImage sub = ImageIO.read(file); 
            return toCompatibleImage(sub);
        }
        catch (IOException e) { 
            System.out.println("Image load failed: " +fileName);
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }
```

This all works beautifully in eclipse but no luck on the Jar. Any advice would be wonderful. If having the entirety of my project would help troubleshoot it's located publically at github.com/madamsmall/carnie
Thank you!

Comment: Where do you have your images saved at?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Cannot read image in jar](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15243928/cannot-read-image-in-jar) among numerous others.

Answer (score 0):

An Image in jar file is no longer a `File`, you need to change your code [to read it as resource from classpath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5232778/how-to-read-xml-schema-from-jar-file-in-a-servlet-context)

Answer (score 0):

Could you please look inside of the .jar file and see if this location exist "Resources/Images/shop/" and if the file is being packaged correctly?

The only time I have seen this behavior is when the package instruction on a POM file (Maven) is incorrect.

Thanks.

My bad, totally miss that, that answer is correct is a resource.